# With Django, what's the correct way to set up paths to the admin content and static content?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Django site set up that uses the Django admin panel, prefixed with `/media/`, as well as static site content in a directory called `/static/`. The admin media stuff, of course, lives within the Django package, and the site's static content is stored along with the Python code for the site.

Currently, my `public_html` just contains appropriately-named symlinks to the directories that actually hold the static content, as follows:

```
~/public_html/
    .htaccess
    media -> $HOME/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    site.fcgi
    site -> $HOME/mysite/public/static/
```

And these are the rewrite rules I'm using in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, using symlinks in this way feels like a...hack, and it seems like I could use rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` to avoid using symlinks. (I also want to eventually add a `robots.txt` file and a favicon file, without having to add -- and maintain -- a bunch of symlinks.) Is this a good idea, and if so, how do I do that?

---

For future reference, I ultimately did something akin to how Rails projects are generally set up. My Django project contains a `public` directory, which includes static site content, the FastCGI script, and the `.htaccess` file, among other things, so it looks sort of like this:

```
~/
    django/
        public/
            .htaccess
            content/
            favicon.ico
            media@ -> /symlink/to/django/admin/media/
            site.fcgi
            static/
```

And then, `~/public_html` is just symlinked to `~/django/public`. Everything works fine, so I'm happy.

Comment: Are you restricted to installing under a user account and using .htaccess instead of modifying Apache's configuration? If so, please state that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use

```
Alias /media /home/akaihola/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
Alias /static /home/akaihola/mysite/public/static/
```

but I do it in a real Apache configuration file instead of `.htaccess` and I use mod_wsgi, although I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: I think it does -- from what I understand (from reading the documentation and browsing around online), you can't use mod_alias in a .htaccess file. At any rate, I know my server doesn't allow it, because I got an error about mod_alias when I attempted what you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Symlinks are not a "hack" - they're legitimate and useful entities in the filesystem. They're no or more less fragile than any kind of file, they reduce redundancy, and reduce the amount of apache configuration you need to do. I'm not quite following why it is you'd want to avoid them. The symlink solution is far more elegant than writing apache rules, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't symlink for either...

I use the webserver's rewrites to point `/media/(.*)` directly to my media directory and `/admin\-media/(.*)` directly to my admin media. I should stress that these rewrites occur before it gets to the django fastcgi rewrite. I'd give you my code, but I'm using Cherokee instead of Apache.

I don't see why you need to have a "physical" representation in your site root...

Comment: Neither do I, which is why I'm asking how to fix it. ;)

Comment: I just explained how. Rewrite to their absolute (real) locations rather than symlinking and rewriting to the symlinks.

Comment: I know what to do, just not how to do it correctly using mod_rewrite. I'm not terribly familiar with rewrite rules.

Comment: In your .htaccess, is it even possible to rewrite to locations outside the document tree?

Comment: Dreamhost suggests linking in their setup: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Django#Media_Files

Comment: @akaihola: Thanks for the link -- that's insightful, too!